# New instance problems in fiware cloud

Tags: fiware

I have a running instance in the Fiware Cloud (in the region Spain) but I'm not able to instanciate a new image. I continously get an error status. What can I do?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

region Spain is out of scope of resources. Try with another region!

Best!